# Subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{16}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I wonder, is there any subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{4}$? It seems like the answer is no since $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{4}$, but I want to know more
explicit and accurate proof. Or may be there is some classification of all subgroups of any finite abelian group like the one we have for $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots\oplus\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The answer is indeed no. Try to think which elements could possibly belong to such a subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.

For instance you can argue that there's $12$ elements of order $4$ in $\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_4.$   But in $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_{16}$, there's only $4.$

Actually for finitely generated abelian groups the invariant factors of a subgroup have to divide those of the parent group. So since $4\not \mid 2,$ that's another way.

Comment: Thank you! But aren't there 8 elements of order 4 in $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{16}$? The proof is still correct though.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{16}$ has $\varphi (4)=2$ elements of order $4.$  Pair those with either element of $\Bbb Z_2,$ for $4.$